# SwiftUI Navigation Bar Items - replace EditButton() with SF Symbol

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, sf-symbols, navigationbaritems

When I run this code, I can't **EDIT** the **LIST** which doesn't display the **DELETE** and **MOVE** UI when the user taps Edit.

My original code with the TEXT works.

Apple **EditButton** docs - a button that toggles the edit mode environment value.

[Apples docs EditButton[1](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/editbutton)

Perhaps I could get to use EditMode

```
NavigationView {
    }
        .navigationTitle("Make My Own ✍")
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                HStack {
                    NavigationLink(destination: EditButton()) {
                        Image(systemName: "pencil")
                    }
                    
                    NavigationLink(destination: MakeMyOwnAddView()) {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

[Apple List Edit Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdQTN.png)

[List Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyQ2v.png)

[Add View Works Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRpT8.png)

[Edit Pencil Icon Clicked Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8Q0F.png)

[Edit Text Clicked Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7fpk.png)

Comment: What part are you having issues with?

Comment: I want to replace the text Edit `EditButton()` with the SF Symbols `Image(systemName: "pencil")`. Do I need to use Buttons inside an `HStack`

Answer (score 1):

I am not too sure what you are trying to ask; it is very vague, thus I will answer many variants of your question.

### Change "Edit" to Pencil Icon (While preserving the + icon??)

Yes I believe you would need to change it. The `EditButton()` environment object creates a button that helps manage any Views depending on the `environment(\.edit)`. You could change it in two ways:

Using a Button with a label of an Image

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Text("Hello, world!")
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    HStack {
                        Button(action: {}) {
                            Image(systemName: "pencil")
                        }
                        
                        Button(action: {}) {
                            Image(systemName: "plus")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

I would advise putting two buttons next to each other on the right if you can. Try to put one of them on the left side. If the left side is taken up, then move elements into a `Menu` on the left side, but keep the right toolbar open for the most important action. All other actions can be shoved into the `Menu`, ranging from importance and buttonRoles, like it being destructive.    Note: Taken from [Apple's Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/components/menus-and-actions/menus#organization)

### Use a NavigationLink

If you mustn't use a Button, wrap elements in a `NavigationLink`. Of course, the only noticeable difference is that a Button can fire instantaneous code, whereas the NavigationLink pushes to a destination based on criteria.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Text("Hello, world!")
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    HStack {
                        NavigationLink(destination: EmptyView()) {
                            Image(systemName: "pencil")
                        }
                        
                        NavigationLink(destination: EmptyView()) {
                            Image(systemName: "plus")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]